# Write to same mongoDB from different servers

Tags: mongodb

I have a shared storage partition.
I use 3 different servers to collect some data from the web.
I want to insert all these data to a *common* DB. Is there any way I can do it in mongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/) is a database *server* program. So you install a *single* server program (on one machine) and let your three applications access it as a client (each) thru TCP/IP.

Don't have three mongodb servers sharing the same shared disk partition or remote network file system (à la NFS).

(the server word has two different meanings: server programs and server machines; I am using it for server programs)